# python multiple socket connection

Tags: python, sockets

I have a socket server defined below and created a client as well. They are able to communicate each other without issues.

Now, multiple applications needs to connect to this socket server and will push the data. Different clients subscribed to this server will read the data from the server.

How can I have my applications connect to this server and start writing the data even without the client connecting to it.

```
import socket
import sys
import time

def socket_connection_1():
    # Create a TCP/IP socket
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

    # Bind the socket to the port
    server_address = ('localhost', 9999)
    print >>sys.stderr, 'starting up on %s port %s' % server_address
    sock.bind(server_address)

    # Listen for incoming connections
    sock.listen(1)

    while True:
        # Wait for a connection
        print >>sys.stderr, 'waiting for a connection \n'
        connection, client_address = sock.accept()
        try:
            print >>sys.stderr, 'connection from', client_address

            # Receive the data in small chunks and retransmit it
            while True:
                print 'its true'
                # data = connection.recv(16)
                data = "This is a test message from python socket \n"

                # print >>sys.stderr, 'received "%s"' % data
                if data:
                    print 'data being sent'
                    print >>sys.stderr, 'sending data back to the client'
                    connection.sendall(data)
                else:
                    print >>sys.stderr, 'no more data from', client_address
                    break
                time.sleep(60)

        finally:
            # Clean up the connection
            connection.close()

socket_connection_1()
```

Comment: Your problem statement has little relation to the code you posted. The code you posted is a trivial single-connection server. You are going to need to restructure your server as a threaded program, or use `select` to handle multiple connections. There's a huge amount of additional code needed. As to the question you actually asked: Obviously you will need to stash data being pushed to the server somewhere. A file, presumably? But how much will you store before you have a client to read it? Until the disk is full? Do clients care that they will be getting potentially "stale" data.

Comment: @GilHamilton  Thanks much.. Yes, its a single connection server and Im planning to implement a threaded socket server similar to this - http://www.bogotobogo.com/python/python_network_programming_server_client_file_transfer.php ..I can stash the data to a file and the socket server can read and push it..Wondering if there a better tool or better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are asking?

1. You have a server application
2. The server application produces data
3. You have a client application
4. The client application can connect to the server application and retrieve the data
5. You want the server application to produce the data only once, even if multiple clients connect to the server and retrieve the same data
6. You want the server to be able to produce the data at a time that is independent of when any clients connect to the server

If yes, this is what you are asking, then you have to buffer the data that the server produces somewhere. That "somewhere" can be in a file or in memory.

As an optimization, you can produce and buffer the data only when the first client connects, to avoid wasting resources on producing the data when no client connects.

You will need some logic to decide when to delete ("purge") the buffered data, to free the storage capacity when no more clients will connect.

If your application can produce multiple types of data and your storage capacity is limited, you will need some logic to decide which data to purge to make room for new data that you want to produce.

Now we are getting close to the concept of a "cache".